# Creating complex header and footer for my angular pages

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

We have a website of 30+ different pages.

All pages have the same header and footer.

The header and footer each contain a lot of logic and calls to nodejs for data.

How would I go about doing this in a smart way in Angular. Right now there is too much copy/paste and I see the same code again and again.

Should I write a header/footer controller and then call them on each page?

Or is there a way to setup header/footer once, and keep them cached for all pages (they rarely change)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use directive that returns a specific template of footer or header based on some logic you provide.

Sample Code

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.directive('footer', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      replace: true,
      templateUrl: function(){
        return '/app/templates/footer.html';
      }
    };
});
```

restrict is for defining the directive type, and it can be A (Attribute), C (Class), E (Element), and M (coMment) , let's assume that the name of the directive is Doc :

```
Type :  Usage 
A = <div Doc></div> 
C = <div class="Doc"></div> 
E = <Doc> data="book_data"></Doc> 
M = <!--directive:Doc -->
```

Comment: And how would you do that?

Comment: I read about something called $templateCache - is that what you mean?

Comment: Yeah $templateCache or ng-include or directive all will work in your scenario

Comment: Do you have any code examples that I can see?   I learn best by reading code :)

Comment: Cool - I think I understand it all except for the `restrict:"E"` I seen this several places with several letters. What does it mean?

Comment: It may help you https://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/creating-custom-angularjs-directives-part-i-the-fundamentals